# Top row fixed in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible ?

I used 3 label in cell of UITableView. I want to make to first row is a header and fixed position always when scroll. Section header can't show right position of label.

[image]

Lost Angeles, U.S.A should be show on second column but first columns text is too long.

Comment: what does "can't make position and it can't show right position" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the UIView with the content of the first cell on top of the UITableView. When you fill up the cells you should leave the first cell empty (it will be covered by the fixed UIView in the initial position).